# RAID configurations are resetted after reboot-Ubuntu Server

Tags: linux, ubuntu, partitioning, raid

I have configured software RAID 1 in Ubuntu Server.

I have created RAID 1 and now one of the Disk fails so I removed it. I had attached a new disk.

Created partitions as same like `/sda` from `fdisk`.

I syncd both the disks by using:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md0 /dev/sdb1
```

And:

```
mdadm --add /dev/md1 /dev/sdb2
```

Now both the disks were syncd and MD’s are clean. When I rebooted the Ubuntu Server, the RAID becomes degraded. What should I do in order to save it permanently?

**md0**

```
/dev/sda1
/dev/sdb1
```

**md1**

```
/dev/sda2
/dev/sdb2
```